# Why I am getting: No `render` method found on the returned component instance: you may have forgotten to define `render`

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, higher-order-components, react-class-based-component

This is the error I got:

```
No `render` method found on the returned component instance: you may have forgotten to define `render`.
    in Component (at withScreenDimensionHOC.js:11)
```

The error caused when I wrapped the `HOC` to class component

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(
  withScreenDimensionHOC(ClassComponent)
);
```

**This is how I created custom hook and HOC**

I created custom hook:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export const useScreenDimension = () => {
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(window.innerWidth);
  const [height, setHeight] = useState(window.innerHeight);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleDimension = event => {
      setWidth(event.target.innerWidth);
      setHeight(event.target.innerHeight);
    };
    window.addEventListener('resize', handleDimension);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', handleDimension);
    };
  }, []);
  return { width, height };
};
```

HOC:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { useScreenDimension } from './useScreenDimension';

const withScreenDimensionHOC = () => {
  return props => {
    const { width, height } = useScreenDimension();
    return <Component width={width} height={height} {...props} />;
  };
};

withScreenDimensionHOC.displayName = 'withScreenDimensionHOC';

export default withScreenDimensionHOC;
```

Then wrapped the `HOC` to class component

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(
  withScreenDimensionHOC(ClassComponent)
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to render `<Component>`, React's base component class.

It has no render method, like the error says. You pass a component into `withScreenDimensionHOC` but ignore it. Don't ignore it ;)

You probably meant something like:

```js
const withScreenDimensionHOC = WrappedComponent => (
  props => {
    const { width, height } = useScreenDimension()
    return <WrappedComponent width={width} height={height} {...props} />
  }
)
```